# COM Automation From Web Application

Tags: asp.net, com, automation, activex

Currently we have a document management system that is implemented as a windows desktop application.

We want to convert it to web application using ASP.NET; however we are facing a major problem.
The application depends heavily on COM automation specially to work with Microsoft Office documents and AutoCad drawings in order to insert the generated document number in the documents.

What are the possible solutions to achieve the same functionality using web application?

- ActiveX is not supported in modern browsers.
- COM automation in the server is not a good idea! or is it?
- 3rd party tools do not support all the required file formats e.g (word , excel , project, visio, autocad .. etc).

Your help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Emad-Eddin

Answer (score 1):

Just use COM automation on the Server.

It is not ideal and if you were designing from scratch you probably wouldn't do it, but for this kind of situation it is fine.

However I think you should actively plan to remove reliance on COM interfacing with server applications on your server as it will cause you more trouble in the future.

Comment: Thank you. I wish that we remove COM automation, but in our case I think it is a must! How could we insert document numbers inside say word, excel, autocad documents without user interaction?

Comment: You can't do that without COM, but you could move that part of your code and the applications to another machine which would be used solely for that.  In that way you prevent overloading or taking down your main Web server